# HTMLテキストフィールドの高さを合わせる方法は？

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

このTwitterページの上部ログインフォームにて、アカウント名フィールドとパスワードフィールドの上辺の位置が揃っています。

これを再現しようとCSSを考えているのですが、参考にデベロッパーツールで確認してもどこにその指定があるのか分かりません。

分かる方いらっしゃいますか？調べ方もご教示いただけたら助かります。
[image: Twitterホームページ]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

これはCSSのFlexboxというスタイルが使用されているようです。

各inputフィールドは`<div>`でbox化されており、その親要素の`<form>`を見ると、`display:flex`というスタイルが適用されています。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

これにより、`<form>`の子要素を横並びのレイアウトにすることができ、上辺の位置を合わせたようなスタイルになります。

以下サンプルです。

```css
input {
  margin: 5px 10px;
}

.LoginForm {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<h4>Flexbox未指定</h4>
<div>
 <form>
  <div>
    <input type="text" placeholder="username"/>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="password" placeholder="password"/>
  </div>
 </form>
<div>

<h4>Flexbox指定</h4>
<div>
 <form class="LoginForm">
  <div>
    <input type="text" placeholder="username"/>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="password" placeholder="password"/>
  </div>
 </form>
<div>
```

参考
[要素を横並びにするならflex boxしかない！ - Qiita](https://qiita.com/HiromuMasuda0228/items/baf8015076d7d90b8fea)

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます！内容確認させて頂きます！